# How to use progressbar indeterminate in ruby/tk?

Tags: ruby, progress-bar, tk-toolkit

I cant figure out how the progressbar in ruby/tk works in indeterminate mode.

I can get the progressbar showing but it will not move.

an example if I  just use this line in my code

```
progressBar.start
```

If I only have that line the progressbar will be showing and moving as it should.

But if i add line of code under it it will not execute. I had the impression that the .start method of progressbar starts it and the method stop stops it and in between you have the code that should be executed and the progressbar show until it sees the stop.

But if i do this

```
progressBar.start 
# some code (a loop that takes a long while to execute)
progressBar.stop
```

the progressbar is not beeing shown until the code in between is finished? I thought that was why you wanted the progressbar?

What am I not understanding here.

---

Thx for you help but why is not this working. Its just a stupid test. But i am doing somthing similar in the real program. If I write this code the progressbar will not run as it should but instead after the Devil img loop is done?

```
Dir.chdir("c:/temp")

  bilder = Dir.glob("*.jpg")+
  bilder = Dir.glob("*.png")+
  bilder = Dir.glob("*.gif")
  puts bilder

 root = TkRoot.new { title 'Progressbar Demo' }
 content = Tk::Frame.new(root) {}.grid(:sticky =>'new')
 progress =  Tk::Tile::Progressbar.new(content:mode=>'indeterminate':orient=>:horizontal)
 progress.pack

Thread.new do
progress.start
i=0                                                
    while i < bilder.length                              
    Devil.with_image(bilder[i]) do |img|               
    img.thumbnail2(150)
    img.save("thumbnail_"+ bilder[i])    
    end                
  i=i+1                                                  
 end
 progress.stop
 end
 Tk.mainloop
```

Comment: Please add a complete example that executes and shows your problem.

Comment: I bet the problem is not running the event loop during the processing code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a threading problem.
This code should work. Tested on Win7, Ruby 1.9.3

```
require 'tk'

root = TkRoot.new { title 'Progressbar Demo' }
progress = Tk::Tile::Progressbar.new(root, :mode=>'determinate', :orient=>:horizontal, :maximum=>100)
progress.pack

Thread.new do
 99.times do |i|
   progress.step(1) #or progress.value = i
   puts i
   sleep 0.1
 end
end

Tk.mainloop
```

For your indeerminate version that is

```
require 'tk'

root = TkRoot.new { title 'Progressbar Demo' }
progress = Tk::Tile::Progressbar.new(root, :mode=>'indeterminate', :orient=>:horizontal)
progress.pack

Thread.new do
  progress.start
  99.times do |i|
   puts i
   sleep 0.1
  end
  progress.stop
end

Tk.mainloop
```

Here an example how to do it wiht green shoes

```
require 'green_shoes'

Shoes.app do
  @p = progress
  @animate = animate do |percent|
    @animate.stop if percent > 99
    puts percent
    @p.fraction = percent.to_f / 100
  end
end
```

EDIT: based on the added question here a reworked more rubylike version of your script
unfortionatly i had to comment out the Devil lines cause i can't get this gem to work (loaderror)

```
require 'tk'
# require 'devil'

bilder = Dir['c:/temp/*.{jpg,png,gif}']
root = TkRoot.new { title 'Progressbar Demo' }
progress =  Tk::Tile::Progressbar.new(root, :mode=>'indeterminate', :orient=>'horizontal')
progress.pack
STDOUT.sync = true

Thread.new do
  progress.start
  bilder.each do |bild|
    puts bild
    sleep 0.5
    # Devil.with_image(bild) do |img|
    #   img.thumbnail2(150)
    #   img.save("thumbnail_#{bild}")    
    # end                
  end
  progress.stop
end
Tk.mainloop
```

LAST EDIT:

here a working example with mini_magick since devil doesn't work on any of my pc's and gives problem with TK

```
['mini_magick','tk','fileutils'].each(&method(:require))

bilder = Dir['c:/test/*.{jpg,png,gif}']
root = TkRoot.new { title 'Progressbar Demo' }
progress =  Tk::Tile::Progressbar.new(root, :mode=>'indeterminate', :orient=>'horizontal')
progress.pack
STDOUT.sync = true

def generate file, out, type
  image = MiniMagick::Image.open file
  if type == :thumb
    image.resize "92x92"
  elsif type == :slide
    image.resize "800x600"
  end
  image.write out
end

Thread.new do
  progress.start
  bilder.each do |bild|
    puts bild
    generate bild, bild+'.thumb.jpg', :thumb
  end
  progress.stop
  progress.destroy
end
Tk.mainloop
```

Comment: Hi, Thx i will try that but it seems strange that i have to use a thread for this? So all that I want to do while the progressbar is showing has to be in a new thread?

Comment: Formally, you just need to call `update` from time to time (bearing in mind that that's actually non-trivial because of reentrancy issues) in order to allow timer events to be processed. I'm not quite sure how to do that in Ruby/Tk. (A thread _might actually be easier_ though.)

Comment: update doesn't work, perhaps it did in an earlier version of Ruby/Tk or Ruby, if you do the step from another Tk element such as a button you don't need the Thread, also if you like it simple you could use green_shoes, if you like i publish an example of that too

Comment: shoes in general is a gui for ruby with the emphasis on easy of use, it should be possible to be used by a kid. it has many implementations, red ruby (a c program with embededd ruby) is the most used followed by green shoes which is a normal gem based on gtk2 https://github.com/ashbb/green_shoes

Comment: Hi again peter. First off thx for your help. I am new to ruby so i am a bit slow. Look at the updated code I added in my question. I am using the Thread but it does not work. The Devil while lopp is just creating thumbnails and it takes a while if the images are big. But I get the same problem as earlier that the progressbar show up after the loop. I tested you code and that did work? There is somthing i dont understand here.

Comment: tried your script but there were a few error (eg in the parameters for Progressbar) and made it a bit more Rubylike, on my box this works minus the Devil, try it first like i published and activate Devil thereafter, if it doesn't work afterwards you know the reason

Comment: Hi Peter, thx again for your efforts. I really appreciate it. but it did not work. It does work without the devil code. But using you code with the devil code block the progressbar starts but never ends. It seems it gets stuck in the devil loop. But in my example the Devil code is executed and the progressbar is shown after it? Strange....

Comment: I wounder why this does not work? Creating thumbnails on large pictures take some time and ti would be great to have the progressbar working.

Comment: because devil and tk are not good at working together, i'll publish a working sample of how i do it, but could accept my answer pleaqe ? this is going beyond your original question

Comment: Hi, You are really helpful. Yes of course i can accept the answer. I just can't figure out were i accept the answer?

Comment: You latest example does not work for me. The progressbar starts but no thumbnails are created? The first puts line can be seen but nothing more happens?

Comment: If i test the generate method without the progress bar it gives me this error.C:/Programmering/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/subexec-0.2.3/lib/subexec.rb:71:in `spawn': No such file or directory - identify -quiet -ping C:/Users/eradgar/AppData/Local/Temp/mini_magick20130506-28880-1unp9kz.jpg (Errno::ENOENT)

It seems that the MiniMagick::image.open does not work. But why is it pointing at my Appdata.... folder. Is it some temporary creation that it is having problems to create?

Comment: to accept my answer, just click the empty checkmark, is imagemagick itself installed and is the path in your environmentvar path included ? on my system it's C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.5.6-Q8, the appdata is for a temporary file

Comment: I accepted your answer. no I guess imagemagick is not installed. I'll try to install it.

Comment: ok i installed imagemagick and now it works. Thank you very much.